# How to retrieve text content from a HTML markup string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing, dom

I am going through values of strings and i compare them to a value i get from a grid.
But the text i get has a lot of unwanted characters before the actual useful one.
But they all end with a html tag , so what im trying to do is cut the value i get from that tag.

Here is an example of the stuff i get in the string :

```
<i class="icon status red"></i>, 1 - deleted
```

and what i want the string to be:

```
1 - deleted
```

So far i have tried this :

```
data.forEach((value: any) =>{
((this.array.find(x => x.value === value['field'])).text).split("</i>")
});
```

Which just removes the tag but i still get the rest of the text.
I am looking for a short solution and not something like this :

```
list = ["foo","bar","foobar"]

index = list.index("bar")

a = list[index - 1]

b = list[index + 1]

print(a, b)
```

Since i want to cut directly from string and not a list.
So what i was thinking is that i would just remove everything thats right from . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you run forEach loop. with slice and split, you can have the string like you want, here you go:

```js
let string = "<i class='icon status red'></i>, 1 - deleted"

let list = string.split(",")

console.log(list[1])
```

Comment: well since i have alot more values then just that 1 i go through all of them to then show them on a form. And i did try to split but all i get is still the same string just without ","

Answer (score 0):

One could utilize [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) in order to access just text content ...

```js
function getTextContentFromMarkup(markup) {
  return new DOMParser()
    .parseFromString(markup, "text/html")
    .body
    .textContent;
}

console.log(
  `getTextContentFromMarkup('<i class="icon status red"></i>, 1 - deleted') ...
  "${ getTextContentFromMarkup('<i class="icon status red"></i>, 1 - deleted')}"`
);
```

The above script could be easily adapted to a more robust approach which returns just the value of the last text node ...

```js
function getLastTextNodeValueFromMarkup(markup) {
  return [
    ...new DOMParser()
    .parseFromString(markup, "text/html")
    .body
    .childNodes
  ]
  .filter(node => node.nodeType === 3)
  .at(-1)
  ?.nodeValue;
}

console.log(
  `getLastTextNodeValueFromMarkup('<i class="icon status red"></i>, 1 - deleted') ...
  "${ getLastTextNodeValueFromMarkup('<i class="icon status red"></i>, 1 - deleted')}"`
);
```

Comment: I would try to use it if not for the big size of all the data i have and the different kinds, since the code is then very messy

Comment: @BrianOrion ... Any approach needs to take into account all the possible input value variations. Thus it is appreciated very much if the OP would provide/share such crucial information in first place.

Comment: Yes my apologies but since its a company thing and only that specific one is an issue i didnt write the rest... and i specified that if possible i am  looking for a simple short solution like @Feki Hamza 's answer

Comment: @BrianOrion ... one more comment ... *"looking for a simple short solution"* is not bad at all if it is also reliable enough if it comes to edge cases. And a parsing approach like the above `getLastTextNodeValueFromMarkup` is not only reliable in what it says it does but simple and short as well.